# ''Standing Order'' in Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary

What is the best way to say a standing order ?

Just to be clear I am referring to a bank standing order where I set it up such that my rent is paid by bank transfer on a monthly basis.

Comment: 我的房租是經過(由)銀行帳戶"定期自動支付".

Answer (score 2):

1. The most literal translation is `常行指示` ('standing instruction'). It is seen used in [HSBC](https://www.hsbc.com.hk/zh-hk/help/faq/internet-banking/sitt/) and [Standard Charted](https://av.sc.com/hk/content/docs/si005g.pdf) documents. [BOC](https://www.bochk.com/dam/more/forms/autopay_en.pdf) uses `常設指示`, which is similar.
2. `定期/按期` (regular; periodical) + `付款/支付` (payment) are also possible, perhaps more idiomatic, translations of standing order in banking (see [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E-%E6%BC%A2%E8%AA%9E-%E7%B9%81%E9%AB%94/standing-order)), but they are not literal. They also do not specify if the regular payment is pre-instructed by a bank account holder.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

automatic repayment
自动还款

or

automatic payment
自动缴费